# asp.net set gmail OAuth manually for my controller and view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I would like to set a OAuth on my login page

I saw this link [ASP.Net MVC5 - Login using Google | Facebook | SQL Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ztupzfmf3vU) but I want to do this manually, I'd better do this without visual default login tools, I want to use this on my own login view page and controller...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good articles, from which you should've started:

[About google, linkedid and other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

---

[The same one in MSDNDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/)

---

[Newest using ASP.NET 2.0](http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html)

Hope it helps you!

Comment: thank you but I  want create controller and models and view from first and don't use any custom model or controllers.